# Find a power series representation for the function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Find a power series representation for the function

$$f(x)=\frac {1+x}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (x)^n$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{(1-x)}=\frac{-1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  (x)^{n-1}$$
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty  n(x)^{n-1}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (n+1)(x)^{n}$$

$$f(x)=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (n+1)(x)^{n} -\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (n+1)(x)^{n+1}$$

$$=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (n+1)(x)^{n}(1-x)$$

This is what I got. The answer in the book is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (2n+1)(x)^{n}$. Can someone confirm if my steps are correct?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac d{dx}\frac1{1-x}=\frac1{(x-1)^2}\neq-\frac1{(x-1)^2}$$
Just a sign error, it looks like. Also, you can adjust indices.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$
You made a mistake here.